# Issue with mkdocs and PIP pip-20.0.2

Tags: python, pip, mkdocs

With the new version of PIP there is something odd happening. Despite this line:

`Successfully installed Markdown-3.2.1 livereload-2.6.1 lunr-0.5.6 mkdocs-1.1 nltk-3.4.5 tornado-6.0.4`

when I run this: `mkdocs --version` I get:

`/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: mkdocs: not found`

Bellow is the full log:

```
[Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:14 Waiting for agent ping
--
2 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:16 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
3 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:17 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
4 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:17 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src775305578/src
5 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:17 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src775305578/src/buildspec.yml
6 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:17 Processing environment variables
7 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:17 Selecting 'python' runtime version '3.8' based on manual selections...
8 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:17 Running command echo "Installing Python version 3.8 ..."
9 | Installing Python version 3.8 ...
10 |  
11 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:17 Running command pyenv global  $PYTHON_38_VERSION
12 |  
13 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:17 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src775305578/src
14 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:18 Registering with agent
15 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:18 Phases found in YAML: 3
16 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:18  INSTALL: 5 commands
17 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:18  BUILD: 1 commands
18 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:18  POST_BUILD: 3 commands
19 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:18 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
20 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:18 Phase context status code:  Message:
21 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:18 Entering phase INSTALL
22 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:18 Running command pip install --upgrade pip
23 | Collecting pip
24 | Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
25 | Installing collected packages: pip
26 | Found existing installation: pip 19.3.1
27 | Uninstalling pip-19.3.1:
28 | Successfully uninstalled pip-19.3.1
29 | Successfully installed pip-20.0.2
30 |  
31 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:27 Running command python -m pip install mkdocs
32 | Collecting mkdocs
33 | Downloading mkdocs-1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.4 MB)
34 | Requirement already satisfied: click>=3.3 in /root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from mkdocs) (7.0)
35 | Collecting tornado>=5.0
36 | Downloading tornado-6.0.4.tar.gz (496 kB)
37 | Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.10 in /root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from mkdocs) (5.1.2)
38 | Collecting lunr[languages]==0.5.6
39 | Downloading lunr-0.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
40 | Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from mkdocs) (2.11.1)
41 | Collecting Markdown>=3.2.1
42 | Downloading Markdown-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
43 | Collecting livereload>=2.5.1
44 | Downloading livereload-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
45 | Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from lunr[languages]==0.5.6->mkdocs) (1.14.0)
46 | Requirement already satisfied: future>=0.16.0 in /root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from lunr[languages]==0.5.6->mkdocs) (0.18.2)
47 | Collecting nltk>=3.2.5; extra == "languages"
48 | Downloading nltk-3.4.5.zip (1.5 MB)
49 | Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->mkdocs) (1.1.1)
50 | Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36 in /root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Markdown>=3.2.1->mkdocs) (45.2.0)
51 | Building wheels for collected packages: tornado, nltk
52 | Building wheel for tornado (setup.py): started
53 | Building wheel for tornado (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
54 | Created wheel for tornado: filename=tornado-6.0.4-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl size=427542 sha256=a01b51efdbde187953647b2bc3141db95cb3a2472dd023c1a23f6919c3d1205b
55 | Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/88/79/e5/598ba17e85eccf2626eab62e4ee8452895636cd542650d450d
56 | Building wheel for nltk (setup.py): started
57 | Building wheel for nltk (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
58 | Created wheel for nltk: filename=nltk-3.4.5-py3-none-any.whl size=1449905 sha256=2d8f44629f6afa5af3df5f49dfa303b9cade2df6291136d4484ec8df89770aa3
59 | Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/23/18/48/8fd6ec11da38406b309470566d6f099c04805d2ec61d7829e7
60 | Successfully built tornado nltk
61 | Installing collected packages: tornado, nltk, lunr, Markdown, livereload, mkdocs
62 | Successfully installed Markdown-3.2.1 livereload-2.6.1 lunr-0.5.6 mkdocs-1.1 nltk-3.4.5 tornado-6.0.4
63 |  
64 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:36 Running command python --version
65 | Python 3.8.1
66 |  
67 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:36 Running command pip --version
68 | pip 20.0.2 from /root/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
69 |  
70 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:36 Running command mkdocs --version
71 | /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: /codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: mkdocs: not found
72 |  
73 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:36 Command did not exit successfully mkdocs --version exit status 127
74 | [Container] 2020/03/25 13:41:36 Phase complete: INSTALL State: FAILED
```

And for reference with the older version of pip all worked perfectly:

```
[Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:30 Waiting for agent ping
--
2 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:32 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
3 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:32 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
4 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src588873966/src
5 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 YAML location is /codebuild/output/src588873966/src/buildspec.yml
6 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 Processing environment variables
7 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 Selecting 'python' runtime version '3.8' based on manual selections...
8 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 Running command echo "Installing Python version 3.8 ..."
9 | Installing Python version 3.8 ...
10 |  
11 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 Moving to directory /codebuild/output/src588873966/src
12 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 Registering with agent
13 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 Phases found in YAML: 3
14 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33  POST_BUILD: 3 commands
15 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33  INSTALL: 5 commands
16 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33  BUILD: 1 commands
17 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: SUCCEEDED
18 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 Phase context status code:  Message:
19 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 Entering phase INSTALL
20 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:33 Running command pip install --upgrade pip
21 | Collecting pip
22 | Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/54/0c/d01aa759fdc501a58f431eb594a17495f15b88da142ce14b5845662c13f3/pip-20.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)
23 | Installing collected packages: pip
24 | Found existing installation: pip 19.1.1
25 | Uninstalling pip-19.1.1:
26 | Successfully uninstalled pip-19.1.1
27 | Successfully installed pip-20.0.2
28 |  
29 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:40 Running command python -m pip install mkdocs
30 | Collecting mkdocs
31 | Downloading mkdocs-1.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
32 | Collecting click>=3.3
33 | Downloading Click-7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (81 kB)
34 | Collecting Markdown>=2.3.1
35 | Downloading Markdown-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
36 | Collecting livereload>=2.5.1
37 | Downloading livereload-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
38 | Collecting PyYAML>=3.10
39 | Downloading PyYAML-5.3.tar.gz (268 kB)
40 | Collecting tornado>=5.0
41 | Downloading tornado-6.0.3.tar.gz (482 kB)
42 | Collecting Jinja2>=2.7.1
43 | Downloading Jinja2-2.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
44 | Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Markdown>=2.3.1->mkdocs) (41.6.0)
45 | Collecting six
46 | Downloading six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
47 | Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23
48 | Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
49 | Building wheels for collected packages: PyYAML, tornado
50 | Building wheel for PyYAML (setup.py): started
51 | Building wheel for PyYAML (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
52 | Created wheel for PyYAML: filename=PyYAML-5.3-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl size=464191 sha256=60a390f451588ea5c5d14be4d0e89760ae859130f5c0f6e492832a5198aa32d2
53 | Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/e4/94/ec/65e430f66fda7a86c08f61ce59455581adc269a65881b4ffeb
54 | Building wheel for tornado (setup.py): started
55 | Building wheel for tornado (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
56 | Created wheel for tornado: filename=tornado-6.0.3-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl size=423083 sha256=4367eb3658c8b03752cbfa3d50253f2a4b9509152598a94d0e19acd6206022a0
57 | Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/ba/65/ba/67a9a9143a42c0738e92073d026851b9365b5150cdb6bec286
58 | Successfully built PyYAML tornado
59 | Installing collected packages: click, Markdown, six, tornado, livereload, PyYAML, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, mkdocs
60 | Successfully installed Jinja2-2.11.1 Markdown-3.2.1 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 PyYAML-5.3 click-7.0 livereload-2.6.1 mkdocs-1.0.4 six-1.14.0 tornado-6.0.3
61 |  
62 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:53 Running command python --version
63 | Python 3.8.0
64 |  
65 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:53 Running command pip --version
66 | pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
67 |  
68 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:53 Running command mkdocs --version
69 | mkdocs, version 1.0.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mkdocs (Python 3.8)
70 |  
71 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:53 Phase complete: INSTALL State: SUCCEEDED
72 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:53 Phase context status code:  Message:
73 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:53 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
74 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:53 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
75 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:53 Phase context status code:  Message:
76 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:53 Entering phase BUILD
77 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:53 Running command python -m mkdocs build
78 | INFO    -  Cleaning site directory
79 | INFO    -  Building documentation to directory: /codebuild/output/src588873966/src/site
80 | INFO    -  The following pages exist in the docs directory, but are not included in the "nav" configuration:
81 | - products/cloud/azure/openvpn-server.md
82 | - products/cloud/azure/rsyslog-server.md
83 |  
84 | [Container] 2020/02/16 18:20:54 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Perhaps a path problem; on Linux, try PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin if using pip3